# How to avoid performance issues in user-customizable dashboards by limiting in some way the amount of information being displayed

Tags: charts, dashboard, response-time, reports, customisation

I work for a Product that allows users to create customs dashboards. They have the possibility to create 1-25 custom charts and the available chart types are indicators, columns, bars, area, pie, and line.

The problem that we are currently facing is that some users create dashboards with dimensions that not only bring an insane amount of data which causes performance issues but also are really hard to read and analyze.

I would like to receive some advice about how to:

- Reduce the data that we render in the charts.
- Limit the users so they don't create no-sense reports.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What kind of data are you showing in the dashboards exactly? Can we see some mockups or prototype?

Comment: You should ask the users why they are creating charts like this and what they are hoping to achieve with it. You could just limit the amount of data being displayed in a chart (first 10k data points) and show a banner informing the user about the restriction.

Comment: @jonvyltra - Unfortunately, I can't share mockups or prototypes. The data that the dashboards are showing is requests' related information (such us: requester, assigned person, assigned help desk, type, urgency, etc). I hope this helps.